# Skip loading div content when on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 div classes: "desktop-only" and "mobile-only"

I am using  to show some content only on desktop and hide it from mobile but it still loading the content just hide it from screen. That way it slow my page.

I am looking for solution to skip loading the content for example when I am on desktop to skip loading the mobile div and when I am on mobile to skip loading the desktop div.
Any solutions ?

Comment: how are you detecting the current device? MediaQuery or via JS?

Comment: Currently I am using that way

Comment: <style>
@media all and (max-device-width: 780px) {
*[class*="mobile-only"] {
            display: block !important;
            max-height: none !important;
      }
}
</style>

Comment: make the content `display:none` at a specific breakpoint in your media query.

Comment: `display:none` will be rendered not shown

Comment: I'm using display none; <div class="desktop-only" style="overflow: hidden; display: none"> but that didn't stop content from loading

Comment: You can `show/hide` only **loaded** content. If you want **not** to load some content then you should do something on the server side. `userAgent` string gives you information about the browser.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with php functions when creating the server side page?

Answer (score 2):

The elements can not be deleted via CSS from DOM.

In JS you add add is some snippet like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width()<=700){
        $('.desktop-only').remove();
    } else {
        $('.mobile-only').remove();
   }        
});
```

Comment: Thats good idea , I am not good with java I create js file with that script and call the file but that didn't do the trick for me. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?